# Java Regex needed for a dynamic repeated sequence in a string

Tags: java, regex

```
str  = "sysparm_type=list_data&count=20&start=20&p=incident%3Bq%3Aactive%3Dtrue%5EEQ&table=incident"
```

I want a regex for the above string which should be able to match with the following strings:

```
str1  = "sysparm_type=list_data&count=100&start=100&p=incident%3Bq%3Aactive%3Dtrue%5EEQ&table=incident"
str2  = "sysparm_type=list_data&count=2821&start=2821&p=incident%3Bq%3Aactive%3Dtrue%5EEQ&table=incident"
```

count and start values may change, but we need to match the second occurrence of the int with first set of integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understand correctly, you're looking for this pattern:

```
"sysparm_type=list_data&count=(\\d+)&start=\\1&p=incident%3Bq%3Aactive%3Dtrue%5EEQ&table=incident"
```

The \1 there is called a backreference, it will match whatever was matched in the 1st capturing group.

Comment: It worked. You've nailed it. This is what I was looking for the back-reference class. Thanks a ton....